# Stepwise Algorithm in Tidymodels

Tags: r, tidymodels, r-recipes, r-parsnip

I found that the Stepwise Algorithm for variable selection implemented natively in R with `step()` is not integrated in Tidymodels.

I do not know if there is a reason for not using it (because of better procedures), or is it simply a lacking feature.

Comment: Yep, we are unlikely to build support for [stepwise variable selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836/algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection/20856#20856) in tidymodels itself. If you are looking for variable selection, you might consider lasso regularization instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Didn't see Julia's message... what she said)

It's not a huge priority since other methods (e.g. regularization) are uniformly superior methods to feature selection.

You could create a [custom engine](https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/develop/models/) to do so or [submit an issue for it](https://github.com/tidymodels/parsnip/issues)

Comment: Can I use regularization to select features, and then use the variables selected there to fit a model using classical methods? I realize the parameters estimates will be different, but we really need to do inference. And my understanding is that regularization does not produce inference...

Comment: I think my question is implicitly answered (no pun intended) by https://bookdown.org/max/FES/classes-of-feature-selection-methodologies.html